# 1970s (?) story about a man who was moving very slowly compared to "real life"

Tags: story-identification

I'm pretty sure I read this story in school in the 8th grade (1982ish). It was about a man who thinks he has found an eternal life potion. He feeds it to a mouse, and, when nothing happens to the mouse, he drinks it himself. He begins to realize that the mouse's movements are slowing down. He times himself doing things and realizes that he has slowed down also but, from his perspective, he seems to be doing things at the same rate he always has. He decides to type his story and then commit suicide. His story ends "this will be the final iron..." The story then shifts from first person to an italicized statement that makes it clear the man is a museum exhibit. The visitors to the museum can watch him still slowly moving his hand to type the final "y" in "irony".

The story might have been in one of those Scholastic magazines that we used to read in school.

Comment: D. D. Sharp's classic short story "The Eternal Man" is almost exactly the same, except that the lab animal is a rat, and the man is completely immobilized. You can read it [here](https://archive.org/details/Startling_Stories_v01n01_1939_01/page/n95).

Comment: That's not it, but thank you for the suggestion.